# How to join two API in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I want to simulate a micro blogging application to learn Angular 2.

I am using the following json placeholder links:

- [users](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)
- [post](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

As you can see, the post api has `userId`, (and not `username`). If I have to display the user name while listing all post, would I require another API with both post and user name, or can it be done using two different calls to the above APIs?

This is the way I will be listing the post :-

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <div>{{post.userId}}</div>
    <div>{{post.id}}</div>
    <div>{{post.title}}</div>
    <div>{{post.body}}</div>
</li>
```

As you can see, here based on the api call, I am getting userId...Instead of that I want it to display user's name

Comment: Your controller can depend on more than one service: angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, userService, postService) { ...  }); so, there is no limitation on how many services you need to call

Comment: @zameb what you wrote is angularjs syntax (and logic) not Angular2

Comment: True, my mistake...  I was reviewing AngularJs tags and ended here

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in angular is using services. You don't directly call to an API from within your component. You need to create a "service" to deal with APIs, then inject your service in your component and consume them in there.

In your particular scenario, you will have two services, a "UserService" and a "PostService". Each of those services have a proper "get" method that calls to an API. Then in your component, you inject both those services and call their respective methods separately.

---

Regarding your specific update on the question, imagine you have a "posts" array and a "users" array after you have received your result from the API. Now, pay attention to the following logic:

```
for (let i=0; i<posts.length; i++)
{
    posts[i].username = users.filter(u => u.id === posts[i].userId)[0].username
}
```

What we did here is iterating through all "posts" and adding a "username" attribute to each of them by cross referencing them to the users array. Just make sure you use the right syntax and case sensitivity as I have not tested this line and just included the logic in it

Comment: I just updated the question with sample code. I understand the part with service and making the get request. Lets say I did it and got the posts data. I listed them using the above code. Now, as per your answer, how do I convert the userId to the userName.....

Comment: @StacyJ I have updated my answer. If it does help you understand the solution, please mark it as "accepted" otherwise get back to me.

Answer (score 0):

Both the options are viable..

1. You can create another API that responds with the required data. The new API can cal the controller functions of the previous API endpoints and return the data in the required format.

**note**: this is possible if you are working with your own server.

2. you can also chain the API calls if you want to work with the existing APIs.. Call the user api and then when you get the user details, in the subscribe handler, make another request to the posts API.

**note** the only problem i can see with this approach is the number of requests.. as there will be a posts request for each user.

In the End the decision is yours. you'll have to see the pros and cons.. If the server code is also yours, ill suggest the first approach..